# Facebook Graph API v1.0 data size limit for JSON return object?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Does Facebook's Graph API have some sort of limit on the size of the JSON object that is returned from its queries?

When I request a lot of a user's friends information, I sometimes get an error code of 1 - unknown error.  This happens when I run the following query for a user that has a lot of Facebook friends (200 and up)

```
me/friends/?fields=id,name,gender,birthday,cover,significant_other,languages,education,work,
checkins.limit(1).fields(place,id,created_time),
likes.limit(5).fields(id,name,created_time),
statuses.limit(5).fields(message,updated_time),
movies.limit(5).fields(name,created_time,id),
music.limit(5).fields(name,created_time,id),
books.limit(5).fields(name,created_time,id),
games.limit(5).fields(name,created_time,id),
interests.limit(5).fields(name)
```

I tried this on the Graph Explorer and it returned this error

```
{
  "error": "Request failed"
}
```

If I run the same request with fewer friends (125 or so), I get back all the data I expect.

It seems like the error is happening because the number of bytes in the JSON that is returned is larger than some threshold, but I haven't seen anything in the docs to corroborate this.

Would what cause this error to happen?  Has anyone faced this issue before?  Any ideas of how to mitigate this?

### Solutions I've Considered

- Limit the number of friends returned, and if the error still occurs, lower that limit for the next batch, and if still the error occurs, lower the limit again, etc - this solution isn't ideal but will probably work for most cases
- Split up the queries into multiple requests - this approach would increase the API calls significantly (risking throttling) since it is no longer part of one paged request
- Use FQL instead of Graph API - I haven't done enough research into this, but I believe that I would have to query each entity (likes, checkins, etc) one at a time which would increase the API calls significantly and risk throttling

In the end, all of these solutions are still subject to same Unknown Error to some degree since I can't predict the size of the object that will be returned (a status message could be a few words or a few paragraphs). It would be ideal to get a handle as to why this error is happening before going off and implementing a work around.

Thanks in advance!